# Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object

Tags: php, arrays

I have a written a code a week back and it was working fine. But today when I chekced it gave me some problem like

```
Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given in /home/ccc/public_html/horoscope/xml2json.php on line 182

Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given in /home/ccc/public_html/horoscope/xml2json.php on line 182

Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given in /home/ccc/public_html/horoscope/xml2json.php on line 182

Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given in /home/ccc/public_html/horoscope/xml2json.php on line 182

Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given in /home/ccc/public_html/horoscope/xml2json.php on line 182
```

The part of my code is

```
$currentDate = date("n/j/Y"); 
 echo($hdate);
require_once("xml2json.php");

$testXmlFile = "http://www.findyourfate.com/rss/horoscope-astrology-feed.asp?mode=view&todate=$currentDate";
echo($testXmlFile);
$xmlStringContents = file_get_contents($testXmlFile); 
$jsonContents = "";
$jsonContents = xml2json::transformXmlStringToJson($xmlStringContents);
$obj =json_decode($jsonContents);
$rows = array();
foreach($obj->rss->channel->item as $item)
```

the 182 line in xml2json is

```
if (get_class($simpleXmlElementObject) == SIMPLE_XML_ELEMENT_PHP_CLASS) {
    // Get a copy of the simpleXmlElementObject
    $copyOfsimpleXmlElementObject = $simpleXmlElementObject;
    // Get the object variables in the SimpleXmlElement object for us to iterate.
    $simpleXmlElementObject = get_object_vars($simpleXmlElementObject);
}
```

here is the pastebin link for var_dump of simpleXMLElement Object

http://pastebin.com/MPQfdQVx

Can someone please help me out that what suddenly happened that its not working.

Thanks

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump($simpleXmlElementObject);`

Comment: `$simpleXmlElementObject` is a string, not an object. How is it initialised?

Comment: @Hanky Panky Here is the pastebin link for the var_dump of simpleXML

http://pastebin.com/w97CD5m3

Answer (score 6):

simply add is_object check

```
if (is_object($simpleXmlElementObject) && get_class($simpleXmlElementObject) == SIMPLE_XML_ELEMENT_PHP_CLASS) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not use, as you are trying to compare against a constant & only using double equals (==) not tripple (===)

```
if (get_class($simpleXmlElementObject) == SIMPLE_XML_ELEMENT_PHP_CLASS) {
```

But this instead, something like...

```
if ($simpleXmlElementObject instanceof SIMPLE_XML_ELEMENT_PHP_CLASS) {
```

**get_class** expects the param to be an object & returns a string [PHP get_class](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php)

Comment: Nope . If I use that the warning goes but it dont run foreach loop.
here is the vardump http://pastebin.com/MPQfdQVx

Comment: Thanks .. Anyway the values are perfectly getting into DB so I am not that worried. But Suddenly warning messages was little surprise to me.

Comment: Warnings are worrying, because it means something is not working correctly. Did you change anything on the server, i.e. configuration, updates etc?

Comment: Yes .. I recomplied the apache, php today morning.

Comment: I would try & fix the warnings as something is not right, regardless if you think it is working. Unit tests would help to test all scenarios & give you confidence it is working correctly.

Comment: Thanks .. I actually reading a feed and saving the values in DB. the values are getting into DB perfectly . I am thinking not to play with code as per now then.